# token authentication on azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How I protect my cdn blob with token, means actually if I call my blob url in browser then blob is download directly means its a open url, anyone can download it.

So I want to protect cdn using token authentication. I follow this url of azure [azure-token-auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth) but not working proper. Actually I calling cdn like that [cdn url](http://%20https://test.azureedge.net/test-content/test/test.txt?w2d3es1w13rewc23e13dsc232w1sqsce2dfedeftdw33324d32t).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change access policy for your blob container. Find your storage service -> click on blobs -> choose your container -> go to access policy -> change to private